# Keep getting error Invalid ID Token with react-native-app-auth

Tags: android, react-native, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm currently trying to authenticate users with google oauth in a react-native app with react-native-app-auth.

This is my code

```js
import * as AppAuth from 'react-native-app-auth';

import { AuthorizationError } from '../errors';
import { GooglePeopleApis } from '@apis';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

const IOS_CLIENT_ID = "placeholder_client_id"
const ANDROID_CLIENT_ID = "placeholder_client_id"

const IOS_REDIRECT_URI = "placeholder_ios_redirect_url"
const ANDROID_REDIRECT_URI = "placeholder_android_redirect_url"

const config = {
  issuer: 'https://accounts.google.com',
  clientId: Platform.select({ios: IOS_CLIENT_ID, android: ANDROID_CLIENT_ID})!,
  redirectUrl: Platform.select({ios: IOS_REDIRECT_URI, android: ANDROID_REDIRECT_URI})!,
  scopes: ['https://mail.google.com/', "profile", "email"]
};

export interface AuthorizationResponse {
  accessToken: string;
  accessTokenExpirationDate: string;
  refreshToken: string;
  emailAddress: string;
}

export const authorize = async (): Promise<AuthorizationResponse> => {
  try {
    let result = await AppAuth.authorize(config);
    const emailAddress = await GooglePeopleApis.fetchMyEmailAddress(result.accessToken)

    return {
      accessToken: result.accessToken,
      accessTokenExpirationDate: result.accessTokenExpirationDate,
      refreshToken: result.refreshToken,
      emailAddress
    }
  } catch(err) {
    const error = err as Error
    throw new AuthorizationError(error.message);
  }
}
```

On ios it works fine, on android it worked the first time but then when i came back to the project the day after it started giving me an error like the following

> ReactNativeJS: [Error: Invalid ID Token]

I can't understand the problem since i'm not passing any id token in the auth request.
The browser opens as expected, i select my google account but then it returns this error.

react-native: 0.66.3
react-native-app-auth: 6.4.0

Answer (score 10):

Check if the emulator date and time are correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This helped me, even when I knew date/time could cause issues. I didn't think to check it, because my emulator was set to automatically update time from internet - but somehow it got it very wrong.. Maybe after the host-PC had been in hibernation?

Comment: As to WHY date/time can mess with login; when user logs in, a token is generated and returned, which is valid only for a limited time-period. The auth-server includes the time in the token, and usually there are some margin for error, if your clock is a few minutes off from the servers. But if your emulator clock is far ahead, or if it is more than a few minutes behind, it may seem as if the newly received token is already expired, or is generated in "the future" - and so, the auth-library rejects it with an exception

Comment: Bro, thanks a lot, I spent a day figuring out and this answer helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. I went ahead and deleted the emulated device and created a new one, then it worked. Hopefully that helps you.

[How to delete emulated device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT5Vj.png)